# How to Initiate Custom Redux Framework Config File after some function are called

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have just created a new theme using redux framwork. and added a custome Option to it.
and for that i have use some global varible which is call after that. so i am not able to use it.
Can you please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand well, Then first you need to declare your global variable in php file. Suppose you want to set a option for your logo , then , open your header.php file.
After then ,  declare your redux global variable.  then echo it .

```
 <?php global $redux_opt;
$logo_id = $redux_opt['logo_id']['url']; ?>
```

> 

```
<img src="<?php echo $logo_id; ?>"/>
```

thanks